# Is there something like stored procedure/job in Hadoop (Hive)

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, pyspark

I am using Cloudera 5.14 Hadoop with PySpark on Hive. And I was wondering whether there is possibility to have something like stored procedure in Hadoop available?

What I am trying to achieve? Is there any way how to set up some job that would be running e.g. everyday in the morning, access some Hive table and write something there + send an email.

What would be necessary for that - note I do not have admin rights for cluster, however I can run shell scripts via *subprocess python module*. Also, is it possible to somehow send an email from PySpark script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hadoop can't schedule a jobs by it self. you can schedule jobs using [Apache Oozie Workflow Scheduler for Hadoop](http://oozie.apache.org/)

The other way to use simple `cron` jobs to execute a script file